# PrimeNG - remove image feature in all case (use button, drag-drop, paste)

Tags: angular, image, primeng, richtext, ngx-quill

I'm using PrimeNG for Angular 13 application:

```
<p-editor
    (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event)"
    class="custom-primeng-editor"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
></p-editor>
```

I don't want to enable image feature. I removed the button:

```
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const imgButton = document.getElementsByClassName('ql-image');

    for (let i = 0; i < imgButton.length; i++) {
      imgButton[i].remove();
    }
  }
```

But the user may drag or paste the image to the editor. How can I disable image feature in all case?